# Failure to initialize a AVAudioCompressedBuffer

Tags: avfoundation, mp3, avaudiopcmbuffer

I'm trying to initialize an `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` using this format:

```
<AVAudioFormat 0x2818944b0:  2 ch,  48000 Hz, '.mp3' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1152 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame>
```

like such:

```
AVAudioCompressedBuffer* compressedBuffer = [[AVAudioCompressedBuffer alloc] initWithFormat:format 
                                                                             packetCapacity:NUM_AQ_BUFS];
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
Thread 1: "required condition is false: maximumPacketSize != 0"
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong initializer. The header file for `[AVAudioCompressedBuffer initWithFormat:packetCapacity:]` says

> This fails if the format is PCM or if the format has variable bytes per packet (format.streamDescription->mBytesPerPacket == 0).

and as you can see from the format, you have `0 bytes/packet`.

Use `-[AVAudioCompressedBuffer packetCapacity:maximumPacketSize:]` instead

```
AVAudioCompressedBuffer* compressedBuffer = [[AVAudioCompressedBuffer alloc] initWithFormat:format packetCapacity:NUM_AQ_BUFS maximumPacketSize: 1024];
```

tbh I don't know what the maximum packet size for mp3 should be. Apparently it's 144 bytes. You can query this with `AudioCodecGetPropertyInfo()` + `kAudioCodecPropertyMaximumPacketByteSize` or derive it from your own packet stream.